# Appium - How use findElement(By.xxx) for ios scripts?

Tags: selenium, appium-ios

I'm doing ios mobile automation. When i use **driver.findElement(By.name(" ")).click();** which one i want to give to find and click the element, either name or value. **I have attached the appium inspector of that element below** . I dont want to use xpath for this one, and also how to use label to find an element.

> name:  Left     Change Status
>   type: XCUIElementTypeOther
>   value: (null)
>   label:  Left     Change Status
>   hint: (null)
>   enabled: true
>   visible: false
>   valid: false
>   location: {0, 58}
>   size: {375, 60}
>   xpath:// XCUIElementTypeApplication[1]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/

Answer (score 0):

please try below code:

```
driver..findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("Left Change Status")).click();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("XCUIElementTypeApplication[1]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]")).click();
```